# obtain hour from DateTime vector

Tags: r, date, time

I have a DateTime vector within a data.frame where the data frame is made up of 8760 observations representing hourly intervals throughout the year e.g.

```
2010-01-01 00:00
2010-01-01 01:00
2010-01-01 02:00
2010-01-01 03:00
```

and so on.

I would like to create a data.frame which has the original DateTime vector as the first column and then the hourly values in the second column e.g.

```
2010-01-01 00:00          00:00
2010-01-01 01:00          01:00
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `format` or `strptime` to extract the time information.

Create a POSIXct vector:

```
x <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-05-21"), by=("+1 hour"), length.out=5)
```

Extract the time:

```
data.frame(
  date=x,
  time=format(x, "%H:%M")
)

                 date  time
1 2012-05-21 00:00:00 00:00
2 2012-05-21 01:00:00 01:00
3 2012-05-21 02:00:00 02:00
4 2012-05-21 03:00:00 03:00
5 2012-05-21 04:00:00 04:00
```

---

If the input vector is a character vector, then you have to convert to POSIXct first:

Create some data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  DateTime=format(seq(as.POSIXct("2012-05-21"), by=("+1 hour"), length.out=5), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
)
dat
          DateTime
1 2012-05-21 00:00
2 2012-05-21 01:00
3 2012-05-21 02:00
4 2012-05-21 03:00
5 2012-05-21 04:00
```

Split time out:

```
data.frame(
  DateTime=dat$DateTime,
  time=format(as.POSIXct(dat$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), format="%H:%M")
)

          DateTime  time
1 2012-05-21 00:00 00:00
2 2012-05-21 01:00 01:00
3 2012-05-21 02:00 02:00
4 2012-05-21 03:00 03:00
5 2012-05-21 04:00 04:00
```

Comment: The datetime vector is imported into r from a text file, thus I do not simply have the vector in format YYYY-dd-mm but as YYYY-dd-mm HH:MM therefore by replacing the time above with my vector it will not work. How would I convert the vector I have i.e. in the format YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM into a POSIXct vector?

Comment: use the as.POSIXct and stipulate the format as an arguement. see ?as.POSIXct

Comment: I have tried x <- as.POSIXct(DateTime,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") but it returns an error: Error in as.POSIXct.default(DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") : 
  do not know how to convert 'DateTime' to class "POSIXct"

Comment: What is the class of your "DateTime" object? Your question lead me to believe this is a `DateTime` object, i.e. POSIXct.

Comment: The reason I haven't accepted is that it is not what I want, I stated above that this does not work as I was expecting!

Comment: Here you are RJ, I have accepted the answer even though it does not provide the answer I needed. I find it really petty that someone would give a negative vote for the question just because I was not happy with the feedback given.

Comment: @user1407388 You should definitely not accept the answer if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @user1407388 I have edited my answer to also show the case where your data is a charactor vector. I hope this helps - the info you provided is still a bit unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Or generically, not treating them as dates, you can use the following provided that the time and dates are padded correctly.

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(DateTime = c("2010-01-01 00:00", "2010-01-01 01:00", "2010-01-01 02:00", "2010-01-01 03:00"))
df <- data.frame(df, Time = str_sub(df$DateTime, -5, -1))
```

It depends on your needs really.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lubridate`

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(DateTime = c("2010-01-01 00:00", "2010-01-01 01:00", "2010-01-01 02:00", "2010-01-01 03:00"))

df <- mutate(df, DateTime = ymd_hm(DateTime),
                 time  = str_c(hour(DateTime), str_pad(minute(DateTime), 2, side = 'right', pad = '0'), sep = ':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

On a more general note, for anyone that comes here from google and maybe wants to group by hour:

The key here is: `lubridate::hour(datetime)`

p22 in the cran doc here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf